# Explained variance for training dataset

Tags: variance, dataset

After computing the unbiased variance of each attribute in my dataset, I am now interested in finding the explained variance / attribute.

I have not trained a model, and therefore I am simply looking at my training data set. I am struggling with the concept of explained variance in terms if the model is not involved - would I be simply looking at the percentage each variance of each attribute is of the total sum of variances?

I would be very greatful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: If you have not trained a model, what has been explained?

Comment: That's what I am struggling to understand here - what does the explained variance mean? I have a data set with X with attributes. Each attribute has different variances based on its values in every observations. The way I interpret it is that the explained variance would be the percentage an attribute's variance represents of the sum of all variances across all attributes.

Comment: That is not a correct understanding of "explained".  You need a model - i.e. an explanation

Comment: And how would the variance of attribute 1 of X explain the variance of the Y attribute ? Especially if it's a classification - any resources would be great.